# Error using Common Table Expression in SQL User Defined Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetNextEntityID]
()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH allIDs AS
    (
    SELECT entity_id FROM Entity 
    UNION SELECT entity_id FROM Reserved_Entity
    )       
  RETURN (SELECT (MAX(entity_id) FROM allIDs )

END
GO
```

SQL isn't my strong point, but I can't work out what I'm doing wrong here. I want the function to return the largest entity_id from a union of 2 tables. Running the script gives the error:

```
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RETURN'.
```

I looked to see if there was some restriction on using CTEs in functions but couldn't find anything relevant. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetNextEntityID]()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @result INT;

  WITH allIDs AS
  (
    SELECT entity_id FROM Entity 
    UNION SELECT entity_id FROM Reserved_Entity
  )       
  SELECT @result = MAX(entity_id) FROM allIDs;

  RETURN @result;

END
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

While you can do it, why do you need a CTE here?

```
  RETURN
  (
    SELECT MAX(entity_id) FROM
    (
      SELECT entity_id FROM dbo.Entity 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT entity_id FROM dbo.Reserved_Entity
    ) AS allIDs
  );
```

Also there is no reason to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` since this will almost always introduce an expensive distinct sort operation. And [please always use the schema prefix when creating / referencing any object](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Comment: +1 Agreed. Also, for Union Vs Union All - In this case, you need the Max value and don't care If the rows are distinct. So, don't use UNION which gives distinct rows but has a performance hit. Use Union All instead. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/

Comment: Thanks @Ashish but isn't that essentially what I said? :-)

Comment: Sure @Aaron. Because the guy asking the question said "SQL isn't my strong point". So, I wanted to supplement your answer with a link for UNION Vs UNION ALL for his information.That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not return the way your are doing from the function.

[image: Error]

Make use of a local variable and return the same.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetNextEntityID]()
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @MaxEntityId INT;

      WITH allIDs AS
      (
        SELECT entity_id FROM Entity 
        UNION SELECT entity_id FROM Reserved_Entity
      )       
      SELECT @MaxEntityId = MAX(entity_id) FROM allIDs;

      RETURN @MaxEntityId ;

    END
 GO
```

Comment: But adding a local variable then means it's no longer an inline function - slower. Not saying you're wrong at all - just looking for the advantages of both CTE and inline UDF. Please see http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084263/can-an-inline-table-valued-udf-outperform-the-equivalent-scalar-udf-in-a-select

Answer (score -1):

```
create function tvfFormatstring (@string varchar(100))
returns @fn_table table
(id int identity(1,1),
item int)
as
begin

insert into @fn_table(item)
declare @result int 
set @string = @string+'-'
;with cte (start,number)
as
(

select 1 as start , CHARINDEX('-',@string,1) as number
union all
select number+1 as start , CHARINDEX('-',@string,number+1) as number from cte 
where number <= LEN(@string)

)

select @result = SUBSTRING(@string,start,number-start) from cte ;
return @result;

end



select * from tvfFormatstring ('12321-13542-15634')
```

Comment: Only providing code is not a correct answer. Please elaborate.